# T4 Code Generation In the Abstract (No Automatic Compilation, No Automatic File Management)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-generation, t4, vsix

We have a circumstance where we basically want to generate string representation of a code file by passing in arguments for the template contents and information the template needs to build itself:

```
//***  PSEUDO CODE *** //
//loaded from an embedded resource file in a .dll. no physical file on file system
string templateContents = ...; 
//has properties used by the template 
object complexParameter = ...; 

string generatedCode = generator.MakeCode(templateContents, complexParameter);
```

However, we're currently running into problems trying to get the T4 template generation to do what we want. The actual code we're using is:

```
var templatingEngine = new Engine();
//T4TextTemplateHost is our own class implementing ITextTemplatingEngineHost & IServiceProvider
var templateHost = new T4TextTemplateHost(references, imports)
{
    Properties = parameters,
    //this is supposed to be a file path? the generation bombs if this is left null
    TemplateFile = "Dummy Value"
};
var templateContents = GetTemplateFileContents();
var retVal = templatingEngine.ProcessTemplate(templateContents, templateHost);

//if a CompilerError occurs, we get NO code, just a "ErrorGeneratingOutput" message
foreach (CompilerError error in templateHost.Errors)
    //this information is pretty worthless: a compile error with line number for a 
    //non-existant code file
    retVal += String.Format("{0}{2}Line: {1}{2}{2}", error.ErrorText, 
                            error.Line, Environment.NewLine);
```

The problem is that the code generator seems to expect a physical file somewhere, and when things go wrong, we don't get code back, we get useless error messages back. It is our strong preference not NOT have the code automatically compiled, especially when the generated code has an error (we want a full, broken file to examine when troubleshooting).

We also want the output as a string, that we can take and do with whatever we wish.

Is there a way to make T4 code generation work more like the pseudo code example? We're on the verge of abandoning the T4 tool in favor of something like CodeSmith because T4 seems like it's too limited/geared toward a very specific way of managing templates and processing output.

Comment: I work for CodeSmith and we do support in memory templates. You also have access to the full .net runtime. Please contact us if you have any questions.

Comment: In case you still want to use T4 templates I have added a feature to my vs extenstion(T4 Awesome) that lets you view the code file generated by the transformation process.  This should help you in debugging and just plain understanding the transformation process.  You can download it [here](https://www.t4awesome.com).  The feature is available on the Community edition so you can use it for free.

Comment: Thanks, guys.

I did end up going with CodeSmith and like it much better than T4. The big advantages beyond meeting the in-memory requirement are that the designer/intellisense support is better and it's better (though not thoroughly) documented Plus they have responsive support to answer questions and help get you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get T4 to generate anything if there are errors in the template you pass in.  T4 will try to convert your template into codedom with extra statements that write out to a stringwriter, the final stringwriter is then returned as the result.  If there are any errors in the template, the code will not complie and thus it will have nothing to return to you.  The errors you get back should resolve to the lines in the template you passed in, at least that has been my experience.

I am not sure if Code Smith works in a different way but depending on the complexity of what you are trying to render you might have some luck using [Nustache](https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache) if it's simple enough.  It's a dot net version of mustache templates.  It supports basic looping and if/then type control blocks.  I have successfully used it with embedded text files to generate simple templates for emailing and reports.

Comment: To clarify, I don't think the errors are in the template per se, just bad data in parameters. I believe that the transform happens successfully, but the result of the transformation doesn't compile in all cases. The line it gave me was a "using" directive, which is confusing. At any rate, thanks for the link. We're considering some open source tools such as that, but were leaning toward CodeSmith since it seemed more mature and better supported in terms of documentation and availability of personnel to ping with questions. However, feel free to talk me out of it if those assumptions are wrong!

Comment: Debugging T4 sometimes can be hard if you don't fully understand what it is doing.  The best thing I ever did was take some time and use a decompiler like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or [JustCode](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to learn how it really works.  However if you need support and have the budget, I suggest you try something like CodeSmith, it is fully supported.  Right now the VS team supports T4 but it is not their primary focus and I am not sure it will every get a full team within Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. That's everything I wanted to know.

Comment: I work for CodeSmith and we do support in memory templates. You also have access to the full .net runtime. Please contact us if you have any questions.